# Possible "autoprint" feature requested for a web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, printing

I was asked an odd question this morning--We have customers who have a number of PDF reports hosted on our services which are accessed through https (not a direct file link, but accessed by a rest url).

Customers often print these reports on a daily basis.

The request is that these reports automatically print (could be default printer) each morning.

My initial reaction is to laugh, because obviously this is impossible without some user action. But the more I think about this, the more I am inclined to believe there may be ways. For example, if there is some generic "print" user with limited access, and if the browser is left open, and some Javascript on the login screen checks the time of day, it might be possible to retrieve files at a specified time and print. I don't believe I can automatically print--but at least I can open a print dialog.

I know the request to automatically send things to a far away printer from our web services is impossible. Wondering if I can provide the next best thing, and if anyone has a good idea to share here.

Comment: _"I don't believe I can automatically print--but at least I can open a print dialog.

I know the request to automatically send things to a far away printer from our web services is impossible."_ What is requirement ?

Comment: Make a webpage that grabs the reports and uses print on them so that the printing confirm opens. Then make a batch file or a powershell script that opens this page in the browser. Use the standard windows sheduled tasks funtionality to run this batch script at the time you need to print. So each time the batch script gets triggered, the browser will open, fetch the report and open the print window. Find a way to click confirm the print menu. Automated screen clicker, have someone click manually. Alternatively just move everything serverside so you can actually automate the print 'ok' as well.